# How to dynamically add ImageButtons and OnClick Listeners to 300+ images?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, android-layout

Alright, I really need some help here because I am driving myself crazy. I have a messaging app that I want to add about 300+ emoticons/pics for that are located in the res folder. The files format of them are "thumbs_00001.png, thumbs_00002.png, thumbs_00003.png, etc...).

I have a dialog that opens up and displays a small menu for the user to select which image they want with:

```
           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.emoticons);
           dialog.setTitle("Emoticons");
           dialog.show();
```

I usually would hardcode all of the ImageButtons, however 300+ images would take me quite a long time and I figure that it can be done dynamically (at least I hope so). The problem is that I don't know how to do this, which is why I am asking it here.

I need to figure out how to populate a layout file with all of the images (i.e. thumbs_00001.png to thumbs_00080.png, thumbs_00081.png to thumbs_00103.png, etc...), then also have an onclick listener for each. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GridView or ListView. Then make an Adapter and call ListView.setAdapter() to show your image list.
If you put your emoticons/pics in res/drawable folder, you can define an array in your xml file, witch looks like:

```
<resources>
    <array name="emoticons">
        <item>@drawable/thumbs_00001</item>
        ......
    </array>
</resources>
```

In your java code:

```
int[] emoticonArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.emoticons);
```

Or you can hardcode like this:

```
int[] emoticonArray = new int[]{R.drawable.thumbs_00001, R.drawable.thumbs_00002, ...};
```

Then implement your Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new ImageView(mContext);
    }
    ((ImageView)convertView).setImageResource(emotionArray[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

you need to implement other methods like getCount(), just google 'list adapter'

To set OnClickListener on each item, call

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the one issue I have is with the xml file, do I need to add an item for each image?

Comment: No, you need not to do this. ListView or GridView will reuse the ImageView. Just google how to use ListView and adapter. It's simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GridView` or `ListView`, they has `adapter` so they can take care of the `onClick` easily and they has been designed to display a lot of data.